# What form of government exists at the time of Alien/Aliens?

Tags: alien-franchise

In The Alien universe we see that a powerful company has faster than light space travel, off world colonies and their own marine force.

Despite this, they still need to be cloak and dagger about returning a xenomorph to earth.

What is the nature of government on earth at the time of Alien and Aliens?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The Company, Weyland-Yutani, does not have their own marine force. The marine force in *Aliens* is the [United States Colonial Marine Corps](http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/United_States_Colonial_Marine_Corps), a force the United Americas deploy to its colonies when there's insurrection or trouble. When the colony Hadley's Hope on LV-426 went dark, the Colonial Marines were deployed along with representatives from the Company who ran the colony.

At the time of *Alien* and *Aliens*, North America, Central America and South America have merged into a union called the [United Americas](http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/United_Americas). It doesn't seem to be a country, but a union of sovereign states (more akin to today's European Union), where the most powerful one seems to be the United States because of their position as a starfaring, colonizing power, and they also control the United States Colonial Marine Corps. It seems like the [Three World Empire](http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Three_World_Empire), consisting of Japan and the UK (in which Weyland-Yutani, a merger of a British and a Japanese company, have significant pull) and several developing countries, are allied with the United Americas somehow, although this has not been fleshed out.

This information comes from the [Xenopedia](http://avp.wikia.com) and [this blog entry](https://alienseries.wordpress.com/2012/10/28/space-2122-2179/), which cites auxiliary canon sources like the [Aliens: Colonial Marines Technical Manual](http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Aliens:_Colonial_Marines_Technical_Manual) and easter eggs on the *Alien Anthology* DVD box set. It's not spelled out in the movies.

Comment: There might also be some kind of psuedo-corporate governments in play globally as there has been speculation that the BladeRunner universe with the Tyrell Corp., and the Nexus androids, may be in competition with the Weyland-Yutani Corp. and it's android technologies.